# Parsing a string into double and string in C++

Tags: parsing, c++11, stringstream

I have a string like this

```
string myStr("123ab")
```

I'd like to parse it into

```
double d;
string str;
```

with `d=123` and `str=ab`

I tried using string stream like this

```
istringstream ss(myStr);
ss >> d >> str;
```

But it didn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Please clarify "it didn't work". What behaviour did you observe and how did it fail to meet your expectations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the OP worked as expected for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::istringstream ss(argv[i]);
        double d;
        std::string s;
        if (ss >> d >> s)
            std::cout << "In '" << argv[i]
                      << "', double is " << d
                      << " and string is '" << s << "'\n";
        else
            std::cout << "In '" << argv[i]
                      << "', conversion failed.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ ./a.out 123ab
In '123ab', double is 123 and string is 'ab'
```

([Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/835efb47c6ac3e13).)

---

However, it fails on input `123eb` because the `e` is interpreted as an exponent indicator and there is no following exponent. There is no simple way around this issue with `std::istringstream`, which works somewhat like `sscanf`; fallback is not possible. However, `std::strtod` should find the longest *valid* floating point number, and therefore will be able to deal with `123eb`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        char* nptr;
        double d = strtod(argv[i], &nptr);
        if (nptr != argv[i]) {
            std::string s;
            if (std::istringstream(nptr) >> s) {
                std::cout << "In '" << argv[i]
                          << "', double is " << d
                          << " and string is '" << s << "'\n";
                continue;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "In '" << argv[i]
                  << "', conversion failed.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

([Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11133755df06c4f5).)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem for good old `strtod`.

```
char* end;
double d = strtod(string.c_str(), &end);
```

`end` will then point to the start of the `char*` array that should form `str`;

```
str = end; /*uses string& operator= (const char*)*/
```

will then copy the relevant contents into `str`. Since it will take a value copy, there's no concern about `c_str()` being invalidated.

(Note that if `string` contains no leading numeric part, then `d` will be set to zero).

Comment: Thanks but it shouldn't be string.c_str()?

Answer (score 0):

string number;
    double an_number;

```
number="9994324.34324324343242";
an_number=atof(number.c_str());
cout<<"string: "<<number<<endl;
cout<<"double: "<<an_number;
cin.ignore();
```

ANS:

```
string: 9994324.34324324343242
double: 9.99432e+006
```

Comment: @Abhinav. Thank you but this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Newbie I have not provided the answer. I have just formatted the answer